# Celery WorkerLostError Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, celery, couchbase

I want to make asynchronous work done synchronously. I use the id of the data in couchbase as the key of the redis. I upsert couchbase again with the value of redis. It works fine when it is running synchronously, but it fails when it is executed asynchronously.

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.n1ql import N1QLQuery
from couchbase.n1ql import N1QLRequest
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from time import sleep
from urllib import request
from wikidata.client import Client
from openpyxl import Workbook
import base64
import json
import osmapi
import re
import redis
import urllib
import hashlib
import time
import requests
import csv
from functools import reduce

wikid_client = Client()
es_client = Elasticsearch("--")
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://--')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('ATLAS-DEV','ATLAS-DEV')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
bucket_test = cluster.open_bucket('ATLAS-DEV')
redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host='--', port=6379, db=10, decode_responses=True)
map_api = osmapi.OsmApi()
N1QLQuery.timeout = 3600


def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)

query = N1QLQuery("SELECT meta().id, * FROM `ATLAS-DEV` WHERE class_type = 'REGION' AND (codes.osm IS NOT NULL OR codes.osm != '') LIMIT 20")
for k in bucket_test.n1ql_query(query):
    # print("k : ")
    # print(k)
    document_id = k.get("id")
    # print("document_id : " + document_id)
    osm_id = deep_get(k, "ATLAS-DEV.codes.osm")
    polygon = redis_db.hget(name="osm:polygons", key=osm_id)
    if polygon is not None:
        k['ATLAS-DEV'].update({'boundaries': polygon})
        bucket_test.upsert(document_id, k['ATLAS-DEV'])
```

this is my synchronousl work. it works well. it can upsert couchbase.

but here is my celery job code.

```
from app.jobs.task import each_k
query = N1QLQuery("SELECT meta().id, * FROM `ATLAS-DEV` WHERE class_type = 'REGION' AND (codes.osm IS NOT NULL OR codes.osm != '') LIMIT 5")
for k in bucket_test.n1ql_query(query):
    # print("k : ")
    # print(k)
    each_k.delay(k)




# /app/jobs/task.py

def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)

@app.task
@provide_redis
def each_k(redis_db, k):
    print("레디스 디비 : ")
    print(redis_db)
    document_id = k.get("id")
    print("document_id : " + document_id)
    osm_id = deep_get(k, "ATLAS-DEV.codes.osm")
    polygon = redis_db.hget(name="osm:polygons", key=osm_id)
    print("폴리곤 : ")
    print(polygon)
    if polygon is not None:
        k['ATLAS-DEV'].update({'boundaries': polygon})
        bucket_test.upsert(document_id, k['ATLAS-DEV'])
```

it returns

```
[warn] kevent: Bad file descriptor
python-couchbase: self->nremaining == 0 at src/oputil.c:67. Abort[2019-06-26 15:13:03,675: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n18016/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1226, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).
[2019-06-26 15:13:03,701: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-11' pid:7697 exited with 'signal 6 (SIGABRT)'
[2019-06-26 15:13:03,702: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-10' pid:7696 exited with 'signal 6 (SIGABRT)'
[2019-06-26 15:13:03,703: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n18016/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1226, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).
[2019-06-26 15:13:03,704: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n18016/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1226, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT).
```

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4113

```
celery worker --pool solo ...
```

this cli option save my life. it works well. this command run asynchronous single thread well.

It may not be the answer for all situations. This is the answer if you want to do it in a `single thread`.

Comment: Agree, not a solution for instances.  It still remains open.